# Langchain LLMChain.arun() on LLama2 with Not-Implement-Error

Tags: python, nlp

Yeah, so I've been attempting to load Llama2 and utilize Langchain to create a condensed model for my documents. I managed to accomplish the task successfully, as Llama2 generated the results quite effectively. However, when I tried to speed up the process by referencing Langchain's [LLMChain](https://api.python.langchain.com/en/latest/chains/langchain.chains.llm.LLMChain.html?highlight=llmchain#langchain.chains.llm.LLMChain) arun, I kept encountering an error that said "Not Implement Error". It didn't matter which function I tried to use, whether it was acall, arun, or apredict, they all failed.

So here are my codes:

```
    import accelerate
    import bitsandbytes
    
    #load LLama from local drive
    tokenizer=AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("/content/drive/MyDrive/CoLab/LLama7b")
    model=LlamaForCausalLM.from_pretrained("/content/drive/MyDrive/CoLab/LLama7b",quantization_config=quant_config,device_map="auto",)
    
    # define output parameters
    prefix_llm=transformers.pipeline(
        model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer,
        return_full_text=True,
        task="text-generation",# temperature=0,
        top_p=0.15, top_k=15,
        max_new_tokens=1060, repetition_penalty=1.2, do_sample=True
    )
    
    # wrap up with Langchain HuggingfaceLLm class
    llm=HuggingFacePipeline(pipeline=prefix_llm, cache=False)
    
    # Combine with LLMChain
    prompt: PromptTemplate, input_variables="words"
    llm_chain = LLMChain(prompt=prompt, llm=llm)
    
    # calling arun
    input: list[str]
    llm_chain.run(input[num]) || llm_chain.run(words=input[num]) # run smoothly
    llm_chain.arun(input) || llm_chain.arun(words=input) # Raise error NotImplementError
```

```
    error comes from langchain/llms/base.py in _agenerate(self, prompts, stop, run_manager, **kwargs)
        479     ) -> LLMResult:
        480         """Run the LLM on the given prompts."""
    --> 481         raise NotImplementedError()
        482 
        483     def _stream(
    
    NotImplementedError: 

# in this last function, "run_manager" should be None, "stop" too.
```

As far as I explored, this process is called 10 frames. Start on

```
langchian/chains/base.py -> def acall() to   
langchian/chains/base.py -> def agenerate()   
then jump to   
langchian/chains/llm.py -> def _acall() to   
langchian/chains/llm.py -> def agenerate()   
in the last it stopped at   
langchian/llms/base.py -> def agenerate() to   
langchian/llms/base.py -> def agenerate_prompt(),    
langchian/llms/base.py -> def agenerate_helper()   
langchian/llms/base.py -> def _agenerate()
```

I don't know what "thing" I should implement or Langchian didn't implement. the calling code is 100% refer to the [Langchain example](https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/chains/how_to/async_chain). I suspect maybe it's because Langchain didn't fully support Llama? Since it runs smoothly on OpenAI API.